# Unexpected garbage collection on StringProperty

Tags: java, javafx, garbage-collection

Playing around with String properties I stumble on an unexpected behavior of the garbage collector. To display the problem I will provide a simple example below. The main goal is to set a 'flag' (StringProperty) and access that on a different class and finally attach a listener to it, in order to keep track of changes. Here is the example :

```
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PropertiesTesting extends Application {

    // Just a reference to the StringProperty 
    private StringProperty savedReference;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        CustomPane root = new CustomPane();

        // Get the name property and attach 
        // a listener on it.
        savedReference = root.getNameProperty();
        savedReference.addListener(e->{
            System.out.println("Changed");
        });

        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


    private class CustomPane extends HBox {
        private final StringProperty nameProperty = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public CustomPane() {
            Random rand = new Random();

            String names[] = { "Alex", "David", "Mary", "Nic", "Paul", "Marin", "Smith", "Antonio" };
            Button b = new Button("Click me");
            // On click change the button and the nameProperty value as well
            b.setOnAction(e -> {
                b.setText(names[rand.nextInt(names.length)]);

                nameProperty.set(b.getText());
                // nameProperty.get() keep in mind that line
            });
            getChildren().add(b);
        }

        public StringProperty getNameProperty() {
            return nameProperty;
        }
    }
}
```

The code above is just an example (a silly one). Every time the user click on the button the content of it will change and the StringProperty has to change as well, which will trigger its listener and print the change on the console. Running the example above, you will see the listener is only called once and after that it stop working. I assume is because the garbage collector decided to remove the main reference, thus the listener stop working. A way to test this assumption is to remove the comments of the call `nameProperty.get()`. By doing so, the gc decides to keep the reference and everything works fine.

I am not looking for a workaround, I am just curious.. why the gc decides to remove the reference while it is still being used?. Of course I may be wrong and this is an entirely different problem.

System informations:

- Java version : 1.8
- Operating System : Windows 10

Comment: it is hard to believe that the garbage collector is removing live references

Comment: @FranMontero I believe that as well, but I can not think of anything else to be honest.

Comment: This is not a issue of an object being garbage-collected. You're using a `InvalidationListener` though and even though you were notified about a change, you didn't seem to be interested (`get` wasn't called). Therefore the property does not inform you again. Compare the observed behaviour with the one using this print statement: `System.out.println("Changed to " + savedReference.get());` or a `ChangeListener`...

Comment: @fabian Hmm very interesting I didnt knew the properties work like that . Thanks for your time.